# Are these spaces path connected??

Tags: general-topology

I have some question on studying path-connected

$$S_1:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | (x-2)^2+y^2 \le 1\} \cup \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | (x+2)^2+y^2 \le 1\} \cup \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | -1 \le x \le 1 ,y=0\}$$

$$S_2:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | (x-1)^2+y^2 \le 1\} \cup \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | (x+1)^2+y^2 \le 1\} $$

Those two space are path conneced? I think we can visually draw a path on these space without rigorous proof .

Comment: A rigorous proof is not so difficult in this case either. Notice that you can always project and move through the $x$-axis.

Comment: Just show that if $A$ and $B$ are path connected with a non-empty section their union is path-connected as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following two pictures should help:

### $S_1$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$
[image: S1]

### $S_2$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$
[image]